# Piranha CMS to existing MVC application

Tags: piranha-cms

How do I add existing view pages to Piranha CMS. All searches refer to existing models which I have none in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the pages through the Manager interface into the database. Pirhana wont "see" your MVC Views automagically.